# How to define a function with different types of arguments by setting conditions on function's domain?

Tags: function-construction, conditional

I need help in order to properly define a function of $4$ variables.

Given that:

```
    beta[k_Integer /; k == 1] := {0.088, -0.029, -0.010, -0.029, 0.019, 0.012};
    beta[k_Integer /; k >= 2] := {0.227, -0.098, -0.024, -0.060, 0.027, 0.000};
    size = {"low", "medium", "high"};
    type = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

The "incomplete" definition for my function `f` looks like this:

```
    f[k_Integer, x_, y_, z_] := 
     Total[beta[k]*{1, Log[x], DiscreteIndicator[y, "medium", size], 
        DiscreteIndicator[y, "low", size], 
        DiscreteIndicator[z, "b", type], DiscreteIndicator[z, "a", type]}]
```

I'm using `Table` to iterate values of function's arguments:

```
    Table[f[k, x, y, z], {k, 1, 2}, {z, Reverse[type]}, {y, size}] // MatrixForm
```

The output result is:

```
   (* {{{0.059 - 0.029 Log[x], 0.078 - 0.029 Log[x], 
       0.088 - 0.029 Log[x]}, {0.078 - 0.029 Log[x], 0.097 - 0.029 Log[x],
        0.107 - 0.029 Log[x]}, {0.071 - 0.029 Log[x], 0.09 - 0.029 Log[x],
        0.1 - 0.029 Log[x]}}, {{0.167 - 0.098 Log[x], 
       0.203 - 0.098 Log[x], 0.227 - 0.098 Log[x]}, {0.194 - 0.098 Log[x],
        0.23 - 0.098 Log[x], 0.254 - 0.098 Log[x]}, {0.167 - 0.098 Log[x],
        0.203 - 0.098 Log[x], 0.227 - 0.098 Log[x]}}} *)
```

The problem is that the function `f` should not be defined for a specific combination of argument values:

```
    k=1  &&  y="low"    && z="b"
    k=1  &&  y="high"   && z="b"
    k=1  &&  y="medium" && z="a"
    k=1  &&  y="high"   && z="a"
    k>=2 &&  y="high"   && z="b"
    k>=2 &&  y="medium" && z="a"
    k>=2 &&  y="high"   && z="a"
```

The first condition is actualy saying that there are no `"low"` objects (or whatever) in the category `"b"`, for `k==1`.

How can I define the function `f` exactly, so that `f` would not be defined for the conditions listed above?

I think that the solution is to restrict the domain of function `f`, by setting conditions on its arguments, but I have no idea how to do this.

This is what I ended up with (worst code ever):

```
    {{{f[1, x, "low", "c"], f[1, x, "medium", "c"], 
       f[1, x, "high", "c"]}, {"not defined", f[1, x, "medium", "b"], 
       "not defined"}, {f[1, x, "low", "a"], "not defined", 
       "not defined"}}, {{f[2, x, "low", "c"], f[2, x, "medium", "c"], 
       f[2, x, "high", "c"]}, {f[2, x, "low", "b"], 
       f[2, x, "medium", "b"], "not defined"}, {f[2, x, "low", "a"], 
       "not defined", "not defined"}}}
```

Output:

```
    {{{0.059 - 0.029 Log[x], 0.078 - 0.029 Log[x], 
       0.088 - 0.029 Log[x]}, {"not defined", 0.097 - 0.029 Log[x], 
       "not defined"}, {0.071 - 0.029 Log[x], "not defined", 
       "not defined"}}, {{0.167 - 0.098 Log[x], 0.203 - 0.098 Log[x], 
       0.227 - 0.098 Log[x]}, {0.194 - 0.098 Log[x], 0.23 - 0.098 Log[x], 
       "not defined"}, {0.167 - 0.098 Log[x], "not defined", 
       "not defined"}}}
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
 acceptableQ[k_, y_, z_] := Not[Or[
       k == 1 && y == "low"    && z == "b",
       k == 1 && y == "high"   && z == "b",
       k == 1 && y == "medium" && z == "a",
       k == 1 && y == "high"   && z == "a",
       k >= 2 && y == "high"   && z == "b",
       k >= 2 && y == "medium" && z == "a",
       k >= 2 && y == "high"   && z == "a"]]

f1[k_Integer, x_, y_, z_] := "Undefined" /; Not[acceptableQ[k, y, z]]

f1[k_Integer, x_, y_, z_] := 
 Total[beta[k]*{1, Log[x],
     DiscreteIndicator[y, "medium", size], 
     DiscreteIndicator[y, "low"   , size], 
     DiscreteIndicator[z, "b"     , type], 
     DiscreteIndicator[z, "a"     , type]}
      ] /; acceptableQ[k, y, z]
```

Verification :

```
  Table[f1[k, x, y, z], {k, 1, 2}, {z, Reverse[type]}, {y, size}] // 
   Map[Column, #, {2}] & // Grid
```

gives :
[image]

Here are the corresponding inputs (just to help the reading) :

[image]

**Note** : You can also put the condition `/; ...` before the `:=` :

```
f2[k_Integer, x_, y_, z_] /; Not[acceptableQ[k, y, z]] := "Undefined" 
f2[k_Integer, x_, y_, z_] /; acceptableQ[k, y, z] := ...
```

Comment: I feel stupid, cause your answer is simple. Is there a way to use negation of `Exists` so that the function returns some kind of a built-in output, instead of string character "Undefined"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "negation of Exists". In Mathematica `Exists`, like `ForAll` are special expressions (mathematical quantifier that goes with predicates) that are not usable here.